# How to open the top cover of a Shimano Tourney ST EF 41?

Tags: maintenance

My 3 speed gear shifter is stuck. I want to open the cover so that I can clean the old lubricant and dust and apply new lubrication. There are no screws on the top and I am not able to open it even from the bottom. How do I open it?

[image]

Comment: I added a photo - if that is not the right one can you please take a photo of yours or find the proper one online and edit your question to include it or link to it.

Comment: It's also possible that the cable has frayed causing the gear shifters to stick. Be prepared to have a spare ready.

Comment: Yes it is the same one . I replaced the cable but ter is still no big improvement , I even tried the spray cleaner and lube. May be if I can remove the top cover I can replace something tat is worn out. I would be very greatfull of you could help me dismantle it

Comment: You're probably going to have to stick a knife or something in a seam and split it (or just even break/cut the plastic on top). These aren't designed to be serviced, and the low end stuff like this is pretty unreliable to begin with. Replacing it is probably the way to go (I'd rather go for a cheap friction shifter than that).

Answer (score 12):

Page 17 of the dealers manual shows that some of these shifters are not meant to come apart and cables are replaced with an access screw instead of removing a cover.  The manual says not to disassemble further. The shifter may not be able to be easily re-assembled.  That said, disassembling from the bottom would probably be the best way to open the case.  It looks like there are some screws on the underside.

https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-ST0001-05-ENG.pdf

You may be able to remove the screw that gives access to the shifter cable and spray some W-D 40 in there to wash out old lubricant.  Some spray chain lubricant into the same port once the WD-40 dries, might get it working again.

An internal piece may be broken if the lever is completely immobile.  The pieces inside are intricate and do wear out with use.  my 5600 series front shifter had a pawl break off and it was toast.  no lubing could bring back its function.  the other lever I gave the lube job i described and it has been working smoothly for another year so far.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Pinnacle Lithium bike.

I was able to remove the bottom bracket in the end but not the top. There's a little central piece that sits above a screw. You can't tell the screw is there but if you pry the black piece up it will come off and you'll see the screw.

A word of warning though, once I did get under there, it was pretty confusing and I wasn't able to put it all back together again correctly. This is partly because I suspect one piece is broken.

Anyway I think it's a bit of a cheapo and not really worth fixing.

Answer (score 1):

This info is intended to clarify/update Criggie's/Cambrian's posts/update's. It is based on actual experience with the Shimano ST-EF41 shifter/brake levers.

*Page 17 of the dealers manual shows that some of these shifters are not meant to come apart and cables are replaced with an access screw instead of removing a cover*.

I just replaced the shifter cable for one of the EF41's on my granddaughters' bike. Scroll down to the 2nd half of Pg. 17, it shows a rubber plug (Shimano calls it "Wire end hooking cap") carefully remove that plug & you can remove/replace the cable. To remove you back-feed the cable by pushing the cable out from the socket the cable housing normally sits in. To install shine a LED flashlight inside that port the rubber plug was in & you can see a white plastic socket. CAREFULLY push the new cable in, keep going until that little lead cable end piece is properly seated. Be sure to re-install the rubber plug, it keeps dirt out.

I used this cable.. https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/service-upgradeparts/shimano/WP-Y60098100.html

*The manual says not to disassemble further. The shifter may not be able to be easily re-assembled* -- [EDIT] Because they cannot be taken apart without permanent damage!!

*That said, disassembling from the bottom would probably be the best way to open the case. It looks like there are some screws on the underside* -- [EDIT] The best way is to NOT TAKE IT APART in the first place!!

[DEAD LINK] https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-ST0001-05-ENG.pdf

[CURRENT 05.12.2023] https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/ST0001/DM-ST0001-05-ENG.pdf

*You may be able to remove the screw that gives access to the shifter cable and spray some W-D 40 in there to wash out old lubricant*. [EDIT] What screw? and WD-40 is a very poor choice of lubricant for bike cables; you should use specialty cable lubricant.

I hope this info is helpful to anyone finding this post via a Google/DuckDuckGo search

THANK YOU to all who have contributed to this post, EXCELLENT info - sure helped me.

Comment: Agreed with almost everything here, but... *WD-40 is a very poor choice of lubricant for bike cables* IME it's actually a very good shifter/brake cable lubricant because it's not really a lubricant, and cables shouldn't need much.  Anything more is likely to collect more dirt and grime. *you should use specialty cable lubricant*  Which, because it was bought at a bike shop with the picture of a bicycle on the bottle, costs 10x what WD40 costs while likely being nothing more than repackaged bulk something-almost-just-like-WD40.  Nah, I'm not cynical.  ;-)

Comment: This is really more of a comment on Cambrian's answer, since the original point of the question was to open up the shifter and re-lubricate it, not just change the cable.

Comment: @Andrew.. I feel that addressing your comment or going on any further with respect to the attributes (or lack thereof) of WD-40 will lead us down the slippery slope of one opinion after another. Based on the tour I took yesterday when I signed up, that type of conduct is frowned upon. So I'll quit while I'm ahead.

Comment: @DavidW.. I freely admitted that my post was "intended to clarify/update Cambrian's post". His post & follow-ups lacked clarity for how to actually replace the cables themselves. The various posts in question indicated to me that: in addition to shifters not moving correctly people were also having issues with frayed/damaged cables & were wanting to know how to replace them.

Given the fact that replacement cables can be had for just $1-USD to me it seems utterly ridiculous to waste a bunch of time trying to service worn/damaged cables when they be replaced with new ones much quicker.

Comment: The front derailleur cable on granddaughters bike was seriously messed up, replacement was the only solution. I felt there had to be some way to do it, I just had to figure out how. I already had the Shifting levers DM(PDF) saved to my computer. When I saw the "see page-17 of the shifting levers DM" comment, I said to myself.. ok, the info has to be there, now go find it. Obviously I did & was(still am) very happy about it. I wanted to share my happiness with the rest of the world in the hopes that it would help others who had hit the same/similar roadblock that I ran into.

Comment: @MartyMcFly I'm pointing out that your comment about WD40 not being a good lubricant for bicycle shifting and brake cables is wrong - it's one of the better "lubricants" for that purpose *because* it's very lightweight and not much of a lubricant at all.  N.B. how your answer hasn't garnered all that many upvotes compared to other answers and the popularity of this question...

Comment: *my comments are only 2-days old. During that time my reputation score went from 0 to 11*  Woo,  You got **one** upvote.  Which was mine - for the rest of your answer. FWIW, you're the one who can't abide dissenting opinions.  And you're awful wordy for someone who - what, three times now? -  claims to "refuse to engage".  Have you ever taken the time to actually compare your touted "cable lubes" with WD40?  Well?  I've been dealing with bicycles for decades, and when you obnoxiously stand by misinformation, you should expect some pushback.