# Repairing Shimano front shifter ST-EF41-L

Tags: shimano, shifter, parts, front

My son's bicycle gear shifter SHIMANO ST-EF41-L (front 3 speed) malfunctioned (Both levers became free).
I disassembled it and found 3 very small plastic parts on the bottom side of the shifter were  broken and the spring ring which attaches the 3 plastic parts to the axle were out of place.

Can anybody suggest where to get these small plastic parts?
Thanks

Comment: Broken small plastic pieces suggests it is Unserviceable and needs replacement.  Good news is shifters aren't too expensive.  Look around for a local bicycle cooperative who may be able to help with used parts.

Answer (score 6):

> Can anybody suggest where to get these small plastic parts?

Buy a new shifter.  Shimano does not sell replacement shifter parts, so the only way to get parts is to buy another shifter.  And it's a lot easier to replace the old broken shifter with a new one than it is to take apart the new one, remove the needed parts, and reassemble the old shifter with the new parts installed.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42453/how-to-open-the-top-cover-shimano-tourney-st-ef-41  This other question also discusses how it is not necessarily easy to reassemble these shifters

Comment: Note that most shops seem to sell these shifters as pairs but, if you can find somebody selling just the left shifter, they're pretty cheap: only about £13 ($17US; 15EUR) online. Also, a physical bike shop would probably be willing to split a pair for you since they'll almost certainly be able to sell the other lever to somebody else.